# Angular Material $mdDialog with custom options and custom title

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How do I pass the title and text content into my custom template. The parameter 'title' has data, but how to I get that data into my custom template? In the code below you can see I tried '{{}}' and $scope.

```
genericYNCConfirmationWithCallback: function (title, textContent, callback, cancelCallBack) {
    showAlert();
    function showAlert() {
        genericComfirmation = $mdDialog.confirm({
            title: title,
            textContent: textContent,
            template: '<md-dialog>' +
            '  <md-dialog-content>' +
            '       <h2 class="md-title">title {{title}}</h2>' +
            '         <p>{{textContent}}</p>' +
            '           <p>{{$scope.textContent}}</p>' +
            '  </md-dialog-content>' +
            '  <md-dialog-actions> ' +
            '       <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
            '           Yes</md-button>' +
            '       <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()">' +
            '           No</md-button>' +
            '       <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()">' +
            '           Cancel</md-button>' +
            '  </md-dialog-actions> ' +
            '</md-dialog>',
});

    $mdDialog
        .show(genericComfirmation).then(function (answer) {
            callback(answer);
        }, function () {
            cancelCallBack();
        })           
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it.... I just ended my quotes and added the parameter like this.

```
'       <h2 class="md-title">'+ title + '</h2>' +
'           <p>' + textContent + '</p>' +
```